# Distributed IdentityServer4 .net core (multi instance) issues HttpContext must not be null

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

So we have a setup of IdentityServer4 with .net core, on only one instance everything works as expected, however when we decided to spin more instances of  Identity Server, we randomly got issues when logging in or out from the client.

I followed these docs: [Distributed IdentityServer](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/docs-preview/topics/deployment.html)

This is how I am adding IDS4

```
            _identityBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Configuration.GetSection("idServer:apiResources"))
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Configuration.GetSection("idServer:apiScopes"))
                .AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.GetSection("idServer:clients"))
                .AddAspNetIdentity<HeimdallUserEntity>()                    
            ;
```

Also because the server will be distributed I also added this code, note that **certificate** below is shared between the instances (so every instance uses the same certificate)

```
    _identityBuilder.AddSigningCredential(certificate);
    services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)           
                .PersistKeysToDbContext<MainDbContext>()
                .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(certificate);
```

However even with this setup I am having issues (randomly) while logging in and out from the Client which uses PKCE. The issue i am having is i am getting this exception randomly:

```
HttpContext must not be null.
```

Which is being thrown from: **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity -> SignInManager -> SignOutAsync()**
and from: **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity -> SignInManager -> SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable additionalClaims)**

This exception is handled and thrown in the SignInManager.cs class right here:

```
 public HttpContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            var context = _context ?? _contextAccessor?.HttpContext;
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("HttpContext must not be null.");
            }
            return context;
        }
        set
        {
            _context = value;
        }
    }
```

Also note that the **client_credentials** work normally, I request a token and everything works fine with multiple instances/replicas.

:: UPDATE ::

I have finally found the issue, which has nothing to do with **Identity Server**, in our system we use **Microsoft Orleans**, and we have a **Grain** which injects the **UserService** and, the **UserService** injects the **SignInManager**, turns out the **SignInManager** requires the **HttpContext** to be able to resolve services, but since orleans does not provide an **IHttpContextAccessor**, the **HttpContext** can never be resolved :/

For now we are calling the UserService directly. But it would be nice to be able to create/find a SignInManager which would not depend on **HttpContext** (especially since it only uses it to resolve other services)

Comment: there must be something wrong with your pipeline, so HttpContext does not get initialized in time. can you show your Configure() method?

Comment: client_credentials produces a result in one roundtrip (so each time it consumes the only instance) while access_code (like any other interactive) flow requires several redirects where each next can be handled by another instance

Comment: also there was a similar [issue in .net core 2.2](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5144) but it has been fixed. anyway you can reuse some approaches from there to figure out what's going on in your environment

Comment: @d_f my configure is pretty normal:
   app.UseIdentityServer();
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same token signing credentials across the different instances and adding them using the **AddSigningCredential** method?

Don't think this is the core issue here but you should be aware of that when you use the PersistKeysToDbContext and share it across services, then there might also be a race condition when multiple services tries to write to the same table in the database. Especially at startup (when the DB is empty) and when the keys are rotated every 90 days.

Comment: this does not happen only at startup